# Unable to show different font sizes in View page using PrimeNG p-editor in Angular v12

Tags: primeng, angular12, p-editor

I could able to set different font-size using PrimeNG p-editor. I could able to see different font sizes as long as I am in the p-editor as shown like below.

[image: p-editor]

If I save the content in this editor, and if I try to view it in the view page, distinct font sizes are not appearing. Below is how it is showing in the view page.

[image]

I want the text to be shown in the View page with the same font size as I did wile I was in p-editor.

When searched in Google, I got lot of suggestions like the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889006/primeng-quill-editor-custom-font-size-setting-issue-with-angular-9), but I could not get resolution to my issue.

Below is my code for your reference.

```
                    <p-editor class="w-100 form-control" [(ngModel)]="enrollment.description" required id="description"
                        name="description" placeholder="Enter Title and Description">
                        <p-header>
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <select class="ql-size">
                                    <option value="small">Small</option>
                                    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                                    <option value="large">Large</option>
                                    <option value="huge">Huge</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                        </p-header>
                    </p-editor>
```

Can someone please suggest me if I am missing something?